# AttributeError at /profile/chandan 'tuple' object has no attribute 'another_user'

Tags: django

I am  trying to get follower system to work but it just wont work

```
class Followers(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    another_user = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='another_user')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.name


    def profile(request, user_name):
        user_obj = User.objects.get(username=user_name)
session_user, create = User.objects.get(username=user_name)
    session_following, create = Followers.objects.get_or_create(user=session_user)
        following = Followers.objects.get_or_create(user=session_user.id)
        check_user_followers = Followers.objects.filter(another_user=user_obj)
    
        is_followed = False 
        if session_following.another_user.filter(username=user_name).exists() or following.another_user.filter(username=user_name).exists():
            is_followed=True
        else:
            is_followed=False
        param = {'user_obj': user_obj,'followers':check_user_followers, 'following': following,'is_followed':is_followed}
        if 'user' in request.session:
            return render(request, 'users/profile2.html', param)
        else:
            return redirect('index')
```

I am getting the error:

```
AttributeError at /profile/chandan
'tuple' object has no attribute 'another_user'
```

Answer (score 1):

[**`get_or_create(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) returns a 2-tuple with as first item the object, and as second item a boolean that indicates if the object was created (`True`), or already in the database.

You can make use of *iterable* unpacking to set the boolean to a "throwaway" variable:

```
#                  ↓ throw away the second item of the 2-tuple
session_following, __ = Followers.objects.get_or_create(user=session_user)
following, __ = Followers.objects.get_or_create(user=session_user)
```

Comment: what is that underscore for?

Comment: @sly_Chandan: it is just a variable that we use to unpack the tuple and assign the first item to the `session_following`, and the second to `__`, `__` is thus here an *ad hoc* variable we need to unpack the 2-tuple.

Comment: cannot unpack non-iterable User object

Comment: @sly_Chandan: you should only do this for `.get_or_create`, not for `.get(...)`.

Comment: I am getting the tuple error  'tuple' object has no attribute 'another_user'

Comment: @sly_Chandan: but your (updated) question, contains two mistakes: it does *not* unpack `Followers.objects.get_or_create(user=session_user)` and it unpacks `session_user, create = User.objects.get(username=user_name)`, as said, in case it is a `.get(..)` you do *not* unpack, and for a `.get_or_create` you do (unless you are interested if the item is created).